# An inequality $ k\frac{\sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j ( (1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}- (1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i (1-(1-x_i)^k)} \leq 2$

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1,\dots, x_n \geq 0$ be a sequence of numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$. For every $k \geq 1$, I conjecture (and need to prove) that
$$
\frac{\sum_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n} x_i x_j \left( (1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}- (1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \left(1-(1-x_i)^k\right)} \leq \frac{C}{k}
$$
where $C>0$ is some absolute constant, which I suspect can be taken to be $C=2$.

I don't really know how to handle this elegantly, or even how to handle it at all. I'd be happy with any proof, but a short one would be appreciated. It's one of these statements which *seems* to scream for a nice "convexity" or "symmetry" or other "beautiful rabbit out of hat" argument, but any proof at all (or counterexample -- though that'd be quite annoying) would be appreciated.

The "natural" case where all $x_i$ are either 0 or some value $1/m$ (i.e., $x_1=\dots=x_m=1/m$, and $x_{m+1}=\dots=x_n=0$) has an upper bound with a closed form
$$
k\frac{(1-\frac{2}{m})^{k-1}-(1-\frac{1}{m})^{2k}}{1-(1-\frac{1}{m})^k} \leq 2
$$
which supports the conjecture. I suspect this is the worst case, but am not sure how to formally argue it.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is using the fact that $(1-x_i-x_k)^{k-1} \leq (1-x_i)^{k-1}(1-x_j)^{k-1}$, but I couldn't see how to use it to get the result.

Comment: I think it suffices to show $\sum_{i,j}x_{i}x_{j}\left(x_{i}+x_{j}-x_{i}x_{j}\right)\left(1-x_{i}\right)^{k-1}\left(1-x_{j}\right)^{k-1} \le\frac{C}{k}\sum_{i}x_{i}\left(1-\left(1-x_{i}\right)^{k}\right)$, which might be easier to deal with. It is also not hard to show the sufficient bound itself holds if we can show a certain quadratic inequality for $\sum_i x_i(1-x_i)^{k-1}$.

Comment: @S.B. Could you expand on that last part? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming algebra is correct (big assumption at times), the denominator satisfies $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i(1-(1-x_i)^k)\ge 1-\max\left\{(1-x)x^k+(x+n-2)\left(\frac{1-x}{n-1}\right)^k\right\}$$ which is a constant on $k,n$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I am not sure what you mean there (is the max taken over $x$?), and what that implies.

Comment: @ClementC. (Yes.) It means that it is sufficient (but not necessary) to prove that $$\small\sum_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n} x_i x_j \left( (1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}- (1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k\right)\le C\cdot\frac{1-\max\left\{(1-x)x^k+(x+n-2)\left(\frac{1-x}{n-1}\right)^k\right\}}k$$

Comment: @ClementC. I'm using seemingly crude approximations, so it might not lead to the desired result in the end. That being said, I used $x_i+x_j−x_i x_j\le 1$, so the LHS of the inequality I suggested is $\le(\sum_i x_i(1−x_i)^{k−1})^2$. The sum on the RHS is also $\ge1−\sum_i x_i(1−x_i)^{k−1}$. So you get a quadratic inequality as I mentioned.

Comment: @S.B. I think this is a bit too loose -- in particular, that will require $\sum_i x_i (1-x_i)^{k-1}$ to be very small, which is not true for $x_i = 1/n$ for instance. But that case is the "easy" one for the original inequality to hold...

Comment: @ClementC. I was thinking about (very) large $k$ ;). I don't have better ideas at this point. By the way don't change the problems statement without indicating it; some people might harass you here for that (you've been here for a while so you might already no that.)

Comment: @S.B. I changed the summation to $i\neq j$ to avoid issues if one $x_i$ can be very close to 1. The question, as it stands, is the right/final version (but the two should be equivalent except in that annoying corner case).

Comment: @ClementC. Also, have you tried converting thing to exponentials? I find it tempting to use $1-t\le e^{-t}\le 1-t+t^2/2$ or  similar inequalities.

Comment: @ClementC. I wasn't complaining; I've experienced that harassment before so I just gave a warning.

Comment: If you believe the worst case is attained at the diagonal then you might want to check if your function is Schur-convex. It involves some calculations that (hopefully) are manageable.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439649/are-elementary-symmetric-polynomials-concave-on-probability-distributions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't care about the constant, the inequality is rather simple. For all practical purposes (i.e., up to an absolute constant factor) $1-(1-x_i)^k\asymp\min(kx_i,1)=y_i$. Also, we trivially have $\sum_i y_i\le k\sum_i x_i=k$. Now we note that $(1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}-(1-x_i)^{k-1}(1-x_j)^{k-1}\le 0$ (just because $1-x_i-x_j\le(1-x_i)(1-x_j)$). Thus it suffices to prove that
$$
\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j[1-(1-x_i)(1-x_j)](1-x_i)^{k-1}(1-x_j)^{k-1}\le \frac Ck\sum_i x_iy_i\,.
$$
Now,$1-(1-x_i)(1-x_j)\le x_i+x_j$ and $x_i(1-x_i)^{k-1}\le\min(x_i,\frac 1k)=\frac 1ky_i$, so the LHS is bounded by
$$
\frac 1{k^2}\sum_{i,j}(x_i+x_j)y_iy_j=\frac 2{k^2}\sum_{i,j}x_iy_iy_j
\\
=\frac 2{k^2}\left[\sum_{i}x_iy_i\right]\left[\sum_{j}y_j\right]\le
\frac 2{k^2}\left[\sum_{i}x_iy_i\right]k= \frac 2k\sum_{i}x_iy_i
$$
and we are done.

This crude computation doesn't yield $C=2$ though. To get $C=2$ in this way, you just want to define $y_i=1-(1-x_i)^k$ (which is always $\le\min(kx_i,1)$, so the final computation is fine) and show that the inequality $kx_i(1-x_i)^{k-1}\le y_i$ still holds. This is also easy once you realize that $1-(1-x)^k=\int_0^x k(1-t)^{k-1}\,dt$ and you can now rewrite the above argument with this slick definition in the same way, but, of course, that is not how one would guess it in the first place, so I included the crude computation based on the simple idea to replace hard functions with equivalent simple ones :-)

Comment: I most definitely don't care about the exact constant, though $2$ is nice (I am firmly of the school "constants don't matter, unless they're nice"). I'll go over your answer asap -- thank you!

Comment: Also, sort of a side note -- is there a way to contact/cite you (or would you be happy with the MathSE citation?) Long story short, this inequality popped up while trying to fill a gap  I found in a paper, and so the end goal is to provide the resulting corrected argument in a survey. Hence the need for attribution.

Comment: @ClementC. I'll be more than happy with MathSE citation :-)

Comment: OK! ${} {}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

- **A  failed attempt, which gives the $2/k$ dependence but "loses" the denominator.**

We add back the diagonal terms of the double sum, and bound the numerator $N_k(x)$ as
\begin{align}
N_k(x) &= \sum_{1\leq i\neq j\leq n} x_i x_j \left( (1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}- (1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k\right) \\
&\leq \sum_{1\leq i, j\leq n} x_i x_j \left( (1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}- (1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k\right) \\
&\leq \sum_{1\leq i, j\leq n} x_i x_j \left( (1-x_i)^{k-1}(1-x_j)^{k-1}- (1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k\right) \\
&= \sum_{1\leq i, j\leq n} x_i x_j (1-x_i)^{k-1}(1-x_j)^{k-1} \left( x_i+x_j - x_ix_j\right) \\
&= 2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 (1-x_i)^{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j(1-x_j)^{k-1} - \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 (1-x_i)^{k-1}\right)^2 \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 (1-x_i)^{k-1}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(2-x_i) (1-x_i)^{k-1}\right)
\end{align}

We can bound the first factor as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 (1-x_i)^{k-1}
\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \sup_{y\in[0,1]} y (1-y)^{k-1}
= 1\cdot \frac{1}{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k-1}
\leq \frac{1}{k}
$$

For the second, we can write
$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(2-x_i) (1-x_i)^{k-1} \leq
2.
$

Ufortunately, this does not seem to lead to a better bound, since that second term is *roughly* of the form $cst\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(1-x_i)^{k}$, while we would like to compare it to $cst(1-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(1-x_i)^{k})$ (which can be much, more smaller, as we can have $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(1-x_i)^{k} \approx 1$).

- **Some evidence, based on Taylor expansions.**
  If we just take the linear part of the Taylor expansions (which we cannot in general, of course) and ignore the rest, we get:
  $$\begin{align}
  &\frac{\sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j \left( (1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}- (1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \left(1-(1-x_i)^k\right)} \\&\stackrel{\color{red}⚠️}{\approx}
  \frac{\sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j \left( (1-(k-1)(x_i+x_j)- (1-k (x_i +x_j)\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \left(1-(1-k x_i)\right)} \\
  &= 
  \frac{\sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j \left(x_i+x_j\right)}{k\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \\
  &\leq 
  \frac{\sum_{i, j} x_i x_j \left(x_i+x_j\right)}{k\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}
  = \frac{2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2}{k\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \\
  &= \frac{2}{k} 
  \end{align}$$
  using $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$ in the last equality.

Comment: in your second increase, you could use a simple AM-GM instead to get:
$$x_ix_j(1-x_i-x_j)^{k-1}\leq\dfrac{(k-1)^{k-1}}{k^k}(1-x_i)^k(1-x_j)^k$$
instead. I am not sure this will be helpful though.

Comment: also, I am assuming that this came from a probability context? If not, perhaps there is a probabilistic interpretation which could then be attacked by some powerful matrix inequalities.

Comment: @dezdichado I'll try that -- I'm a bit worried about "losing" the $x_ix_j$, since the $x_i$'s summing to one is very convenient; but that's worth trying. (And yes, it comes from a probabilistic context originally.)

Comment: also, using Bernoulli for the lower bound and 2nd degree Taylor for the upper bound, it looks like you can establish the inequality for:
$$n\leq\dfrac{8(3k-2)(k^2-9k+6)} {(k^2-k-1)^2}= O(k^{-1}),$$
which is something but nowhere near a proof.

Comment: @dezdichado Maybe I'm parsing it wrong, but is that condition right? $n$ is an integer, so $\geq 1$ (and actually $n\geq 2$ otherwise the question becomes trivial).

Comment: I mean when $k=3$, then the inequality is proven for $n$ up to $\dfrac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{25} = 13.44$ or $n\leq 13.$ Or you can turn it around and given $n$, the inequality is proved for some small values of $k$ given by the above relation etc. 

This is not too helpful - I am just leaving this comment in case you were planning to pursue higher order approximations.